# How to disable Bootstrap 3 collapse nav menu css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I feel bit pathetic asking this question: I have a project based on [this bootstrap template](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-grayscale/).

I need to prevent the menu icon / stacked responsive mode. My primary menu is small enough that I don't need it. I have tried disabling media queries (you'd think that setting one of them to a max width of 1px would do it) and inspecting the DOM, but I can't figure it out. Anyone know how I should modify the media so that the collapsed menu is in effect never triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could completely delete the button by getting rid the following code, which is inside the `navbar-header`:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</button>
```

Then, on the `navbar`, you must delete the `collapse navbar-collapse navbar-main-collapse` classes to prevent the menus hiding when the screen size is small. So, it should look like this:

```
<div class="navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. In addition I set the width to 1px for this section: ```@media (min-width: 1px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
}```